# XCodeBuild Error building Flutter - iOS App. "Missing Target"

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, xcodebuilder

I have a Flutter project.
I want to build the project for iOS devices using Azure DevOps pipelines.

I have the basic configuration showed in this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/xcode?view=azure-devops

But, I obtain this error:

xcodebuild[908:5053] unable to create build operation: Error Domain=
com.apple.xcbuild Code=1 "unknown error while handling message: missingTarget(guid: "a40ea2..........b3beb2e9f90bde3f49")"

UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unknown error while handling message: missingTarget(guid: "a40ea2d289f72f0.........8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49")}

Any idea??

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I think what happens, since it also appeared to me once. Do you have any connections with UIs? If yes, then check all your outlets that your UIs have in the "Show the Connectors inspector". Maybe you tried to change the name of a connection, and just erase the connection in code. If you see that your connections have this dot full:

[image: Outlets with the dot full.]

If the dot is not fill. You have to quit that outlet.